# Tabulate Area 2 Tool not returning correct area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, intersection, area

I am having trouble with the output of the "Tabulate Area 2" tool in the following update:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/11/26/new-spatial-analyst-supplemental-tools-v1-3/

I have a layer of overlapping buffers (polygon) as the zones and then a layer of parks where I'm trying to find the area of parks (also polygon) that intersect with each individual buffer. The tabulate area 2 tool seems like it should be exactly what I want. However, the area of intersection it's returning is not what it should be and I have no idea why. I've gone ahead and projected both files so they're the same and in meters, and I've also converted one of my polygon files from a multi-part to a single-part. The numbers are off by thousands of meters. Does anyone have any ideas?

The highlighted FIDs at the top should have values of 87618, 23323, 21837, and 280335 meters, respectively.

[image: The highlighted FIDs at the top should have value of 87618, 23323, 21837, and 280335 meters, respectively]